# How do multiple choice quests work in co-op?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have the option to return my bullymong hair to either Hammerlock or Claptrap for two different quest rewards.  I would like the former while my co-op partner would like the latter.  If I return the quest to Hammerlock can my partner return it to Claptrap?

Comment: NB: Once the quest is done, you won't get additional rewards (e.g., the other option) for redoing it in another co-op session

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For quests that offer split rewards in their quest rewards area (there should be an icon with multiple symbols for the reward types), each player in a co-op session will get to choose the item of their choice when the reward screen pops up.

However, with that particular quest, it has you turning in to 2 different people for one unique reward from each. Whoever is first to turn in essentially sets that choice in stone for the rest of the group playing in co-op (speaking from experience). I would imagine that this follows true for any other quests that may have multiple turn in points.

Comment: Yeah this holds true for other multiple turn in quests

Answer (score 3):

Better be sure you trust the other players in your game session if the reward is important to you. There was a quest that would give you either a purple sniper rifle from Mordecai or a purple pistol from Moxxi, and I was playing with public players. Three of us wanted the sniper rifle—but the a-hole who didn't was a fast little bugger and got to Moxxi before we could get to Mordecai.

Answer (score 0):

Each player gets their own selection of loot from quests that let you pick in my experience. I haven't turned that particular quest in yet, but thus far that's always been the case (I'm level 12 and I've done about 6 of them).

Comment: I am talking about quests where there are multiple places to turn it in.